# How to interrupt a program by a key press

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor

I want to interrupt my producer-consumer program by pressing the key T. I searched a lot of answers but i can't figure out **why** it is not working.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
    Produtor prod = new Produtor(buffer);
    Thread threadProdutor = prod.CriarThreadProdutor();
    Consumidor cons = new Consumidor(buffer, 100000);
    Thread threadConsumidor = cons.CriarThreadConsumidor();

    threadProdutor.Start();
    threadConsumidor.Start();

    threadProdutor.Join();
    threadConsumidor.Join();
    while (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.T)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

I added a breakpoint in my while, but the program won't even get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By putting the loop after your `Join()` calls the threads will have already completed by the time you check the console for input, so you'll need to reverse the order.

Further, the `while` loop will only be entered and continue running if there is a key available and it is `T`.  You want the opposite: loop *until* a key is available and it is `T`.

Finally, `Console.ReadKey()` blocks until a key is pressed, so you don't need to check `Console.KeyAvailable`, too, unless you want to do something else while you wait for `T` (such as display progress or check if the threads completed on their own).

```cs
while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.T)
{
    // Do nothing...
}
// T has been pressed

// Signal to the threads to stop
// Set a flag, Cancel() a CancellationTokenSource, etc.

// Wait for the threads to terminate
threadProdutor.Join();
threadConsumidor.Join();

// Exit the program
Environment.Exit(0);
```

To display progress while you wait for the interrupt key, you can rewrite the loop like this...

```cs
TimeSpan progressInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

// complete is a simple flag set by the consumer(s)
// Only call ReadKey() when KeyAvailable so it can't block longer than updateInterval
while (!complete && (!Console.KeyAvailable || Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.T))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Current time is {DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}");

    Thread.Sleep(progressInterval);
}
```

Note that this has the downside of always sleeping for the entire `progressInterval`, even if the exit condition has been satisfied before then.  A simple workaround would be to reduce the time between checks to `1 / n` and then only display the progress after every `n`<sup>th</sup> check...

```cs
TimeSpan progressInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
const int ReadsPerProgressInterval = 10;
TimeSpan sleepTimeout = new TimeSpan(progressInterval.Ticks / ReadsPerProgressInterval);
int readCount = 0;

// complete is a simple flag set by the consumer(s)
// Only call ReadKey() when KeyAvailable so it can't block longer than updateInterval
while (!complete && (!Console.KeyAvailable || Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.T))
{
    // This won't display progress until after progressInterval has elapsed
    // To display initial progress:
    //     A) change to == 1, or...
    //     B) duplicate progress display to before the loop as well
    if (++readCount % ReadsPerProgressInterval == 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"Current time is {DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}");

    Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeout);
}
```

Comment: i am indeed adding displaying progress with Console.WriteLine(), so, do i need to use the KeyAvailable for that?

Comment: Yes, in that case you will need to check `KeyAvailable` to ensure that `ReadKey()` doesn't block too long.  I have updated my answer to show how to do that.